# Complexity of printing all root to leaf paths in binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

In https://www.techiedelight.com/print-all-paths-from-root-to-leaf-nodes-binary-tree/, the code for printing root to leaf for every leaf node is provided below.

They state the algorithm is O(n), but I think it should be O(n log n) where n is the number of nodes. A standard DFS is typically O(n + E), but printing the paths seems to add a log n. Suppose h is the height of the perfect binary tree. There are n/2 nodes on the last level, hence n/2 paths that we need to print. Each path has h + 1 (let's just say it's h for mathematical simplicity) nodes. So we need end up printing h *  n/2 nodes when printing all the paths. We know h = log2(n). So h * n/2 = O(n log n)?

Is their answer wrong, or is there something wrong with my analysis here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
// Data structure to store a binary tree node
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;
 
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->left = this->right = nullptr;
    }
};
 
// Function to check if a given node is a leaf node or not
bool isLeaf(Node* node) {
    return (node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr);
}
 
// Recursive function to find paths from the root node to every leaf node
void printRootToleafPaths(Node* node, vector<int> &path)
{
    // base case
    if (node == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
 
    // include the current node to the path
    path.push_back(node->data);
 
    // if a leaf node is found, print the path
    if (isLeaf(node))
    {
        for (int data: path) {
            cout << data << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
 
    // recur for the left and right subtree
    printRootToleafPaths(node->left, path);
    printRootToleafPaths(node->right, path);
 
    // backtrack: remove the current node after the left, and right subtree are done
    path.pop_back();
}
 
// The main function to print paths from the root node to every leaf node
void printRootToleafPaths(Node* node)
{
    // vector to store root-to-leaf path
    vector<int> path;
 
    printRootToleafPaths(node, path);
}
 
int main()
{
    /* Construct the following tree
              1
            /   \
           /     \
          2       3
         / \     / \
        4   5   6   7
               /     \
              8       9
    */
 
    Node* root = new Node(1);
    root->left = new Node(2);
    root->right = new Node(3);
    root->left->left = new Node(4);
    root->left->right = new Node(5);
    root->right->left = new Node(6);
    root->right->right = new Node(7);
    root->right->left->left = new Node(8);
    root->right->right->right = new Node(9);
 
    // print all root-to-leaf paths
    printRootToleafPaths(root);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is O(n log n) for a *balanced* binary tree, but for an arbitrary binary tree, the worst case is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Consider a tree consisting of:

1. n/2 nodes in a linked list on their rightChild pointers; and
2. At the end of that, n/2 nodes arranged into a tree with n/4 leaves.

Since the n/4 leaves are all more than n/2 nodes deep, there are more than n<sup>2</sup>/8 total nodes in all the paths, and that is O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Answer (score 0):

The time comlexity of finding path is O(n) where it iterates through all nodes once.

The time comlexity of "print one path" is O(log n).
To print all paths (n/2 leaf), it takes O( n log n )

Then you need to compare node traverse cost and print path cost.
I believe in most of modern OS, print cost is much greater than node traverse cost.

So the actual time complexity is O(n log n) ( for print ).

I assume the website might ignore print cost so it claims time complexity is O(n).

Comment: But there are O(n) paths that we need to print, so it should be O(n log n) to print all paths?

Comment: @roulette01 Ah you're right. It should be O( n log n ) for printing all paths.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm traverses O(n) nodes.  The total prints it does is O(n lg n) for a balanced tree or O(n^2) for an arbitrary tree.

It depends on what operations have cost.

For example, storing or incrementing an n bit number or pointer is often treated as an O(1) operation.  In any physical computer, if you have 2^100 nodes you'll need lg(2^100) bit pointers (or node names) which will require more time to copy than 64 or 32 bit node names.  Jn a certain sense, copying a pointer should take O(lg n) time!

But we don't care.  We implicitly set the price of operations, and give O notation costs in terms of those operations.

Here, it is plausible they counted printing the entire path as an O(1) operation, and counted node traversals, to get an O(n) cost.  Maybe they did  it even notice, no more than you noticed the max node count implied by 32 or 64 bit pointers.  They failed to tell you how they are pricing things.

The same thing happens in the specification of std library algorithms; it guarantees a max number of calls of a predicate.